# bash.exe opens in root directory when launching from command line in subdirectory

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am attempting to make a script using python to set up a work space with multiple bash windows.

I use the following lines:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\\Users\Patrick\AppData\Local\lxss\home\Patrick\catkin_ws')
os.system('start bash.exe')
```

Which correctly sets the working directory, but opens bash at `C:\\Users\Patrick\AppData\Local\lxss`.

My `.bashrc` file doesn't have any redirecting in it. 
If I open from a directory higher such as `C:\\Users\Patrick\AppData\Local` it opens bash in that folder, similarly it'll open in correct places elsewhere. 
Normally if I open bash from the start menu, it'll open in the directory accessed through `cd ~`.

Comment: Did you run old Ubuntu with lxrun? Or Ubuntu from Windows store?

Comment: I installed through developer options so I'm not sure